# Trying to print current working directory on my shell prompt, output keeps printing more than necessary

Tags: c++, c++11, unix

I am working on building a small shell project and am currently working on displaying the prompt. The prompt should read: 1730sh:[current working directory]$

Whenever I run my code below, my prompt correctly shows the current directory and the prompt, but each time stdin is taken, the prompt and the current working directory are printed multiple times.

Here is my code snippet:

```
int main(){

  char cmd[100], command [100], *param[20];
  char *envp[] = {(char *)  "PATH=/bin", 0}; //enviornment variables                                               

  /* Begin loop*/
  while (true){

    /* Display Prompt*/
    char *cwd;
    if ((cwd = getcwd(NULL, 0)) == NULL){
      perror("getcwd() error");
    }else{                                                                                         
      cout << "1730sh:" << cwd << "$ ";
    }
    //delete[] cwd;                                                                                                
    //free(cwd);                                                                                                   
    fgetc(stdin);
  }
}
```

I've tried deleting cwd and freeing cwd but both do not help solve the issue. I want the prompt and the current directory to print once before stdin instead of multiple times.

Here is an example output:

```
1730sh:/home/ugrads/kadam/cs1730/Phillips-Kadam-Project4/src$ command
1730sh:/home/ugrads/kadam/cs1730/Phillips-Kadam-Project4/src$ 
1730sh:/home/ugrads/kadam/cs1730/Phillips-Kadam-Project4/src$ 
1730sh:/home/ugrads/kadam/cs1730/Phillips-Kadam-Project4/src$ 
1730sh:/home/ugrads/kadam/cs1730/Phillips-Kadam-Project4/src$ 
1730sh:/home/ugrads/kadam/cs1730/Phillips-Kadam-Project4/src$ 
1730sh:/home/ugrads/kadam/cs1730/Phillips-Kadam-Project4/src$          
1730sh:/home/ugrads/kadam/cs1730/Phillips-Kadam-Project4/src$ 
1730sh:/home/ugrads/kadam/cs1730/Phillips-Kadam-Project4/src$ command
```

Should I be using malloc()? I haven't tried that one.

Comment: Pop quiz for you: question #1: How many characters does fgetc() read from standard input each time you call it? question #2: How many characters are entered when you type in "command" and press ENTER? question #3: do you think it's purely an astronomical coincidence that your loop runs the same number of times as the number of characters you typed in? question #4: is the following statement true or false: "The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming is that the computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do?"

Comment: Ahh I see. I see what I should do now. Thank you!!

Comment: "Should I be using malloc()" the answer to this question is probably not. in C++ you only need `malloc` in incredibly rare edge cases. In C++11, since it's tagged, you probably won't find much use for `new` either.